# Data transform in SQL

Tags: sql

I am new here so please forgive me if this question has been asked before or if I'm not phrasing this as clearly as I could.

I am trying to transform the data table below in the format required, but I haven't had much luck so far. All ideas are greatly appreciated.

My table currently looks like this:

```
Name       attribute_1      attribute_2       attribute_3

John         5543              4523              2554
Paul         4523              5543              9523
Anna         2554              5543              2554
```

Where the cells are strategy codes.

And I am trying to transform it into:

```
 strategy_id   attribute_1      attribute_2       attribute_3
    5543            1                2                 0
    2554            1                0                 2
    4523            1                1                 0
    9523            0                0                 1
```

Where the cells are a count of how many times a strategy id determines a certain attribute.

I tried the following code:

```
    SELECT t.strategy_id,
       SUM(t.attribute_1) AS attribute_1,
       SUM(t.attribute_2) AS attribute_2,
       SUM(t.attribute_3) AS attribute_3
 FROM (
        SELECT s.strategy_id,
               CASE WHEN s.strategy_id = a.attribute_1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS attribute_1,
               CASE WHEN s.strategy_id = a.attribute_2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS attribute_2,
               CASE WHEN s.strategy_id = a.attribute_3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS attribute_3
          FROM strategies s
    CROSS JOIN attributes a) t
    GROUP BY t.strategy_id
```

Basically, I created another table called *strategies* that is just one column containing the *strategy id*. Then I am cross joining the *attributes* table to get a table that for each Name and Strategy id contains a count of how many times a strategy applies to each attribute. Finally I am grouping by strategy_id to get the desired table.

My solution works, but I am unhappy with the 'neatness' of the logic behind this. I am also worried about performance, as this will need to run on large data volumes.

I really hope that this makes sense.

Thanks,
Adela

Answer (score 0):

I think unpivoting the data and then re-aggregating might be simpler.  This might look like:

```
select strategy,
       sum(attribute_1) as attribute_1,
       sum(attribute_1) as attribute_2,
       sum(attribute_3) as attribute_3
from ((select attribute_1 as strategy, 1 as attribute_1, 0 as attribute_2, 0 as attribute_3
       from attributes
      ) union all
      (select attribute_2 as strategy, 0 as attribute_1, 1 as attribute_2, 0 as attribute_3
       from attributes
      ) union all
      (select attribute_3 as strategy, 0 as attribute_1, 0 as attribute_2, 1 as attribute_3
       from attributes
      )
     ) a
group by strategy;
```

If your database supports lateral joins, then this could be simplified considerably.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution using a union:

```
SELECT
    attribute AS strategy_id,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN col = 1 THEN 1 END) AS attribute_1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN col = 2 THEN 1 END) AS attribute_2,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN col = 3 THEN 1 END) AS attribute_3
FROM
(
    SELECT attribute_1 AS attribute, 1 AS col FROM attributes
    UNION ALL
    SELECT attribute_2, 2 FROM attributes
    UNION ALL
    SELECT attribute_3, 3 FROM attributes
) t
GROUP BY
    attribute;
```

[image]

### Demo

The strategy here is to first bring all `strategy_id` values into a single column via two unions.  Then, aggregate by `strategy_id`, and pivot out the sums for each of the three attribute columns.